# Python and downloading Google Sheets feeds

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to download a spreadsheet from Google Drive inside a program I'm writing (so the data can be easily updated across all users), but I've run into a few problems:

First, and perhaps foolishly, I'm only wanting to use the basic python distribution, so I'm not requiring people to download multiple modules to run it. The `urllib.request` module seems to work well enough for basic downloading, specifically the `urlopen()` function, when I've tested it on normal webpages (more on why I say "normal" below).

Second, most questions and answers on here deal with retrieving a .csv from the spreadsheet. While this might work even better than trying to parse the feeds (and I have actually gotten it to work), using only the basic address means only the first sheet is downloaded, and I need to add a non-obvious gid to get the others. I want to have the program independent of the spreadsheet, so I only have to add new data online and the clients are automatically updated; trying to find a gid programmatically gives me trouble because:

Third, I can't actually get the feeds (interface described [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)) to be downloaded correctly. That does seem to be the best way to get what I want—download the [overview of the entire spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1Eamsi8_3T_a0OfL926OdtJwLoWFrGjl1S2GiUAn75lU/private/full), and from there obtain the addresses to each sheet—but if I try to send that through `urlopen(feed).read()` it just returns `b''`. While I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, I'd guess that the webpage is empty very briefly when it's first loaded, and that's what `urlopen()` thinks it should be returning. I've included what little code I'm using below, and was hoping someone had a way of working around this. Thanks!

```
import urllib.request as url

key = '1Eamsi8_3T_a0OfL926OdtJwLoWFrGjl1S2GiUAn75lU'
gid = '1193707515'

# Single sheet in CSV format
# feed = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + key + '/export?format=csv&gid=' + gid

# Document feed
feed = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/' + key + '/private/full'

csv = url.urlopen(feed).read()
```

(I don't actually mind publishing the key/gid, because I am planning on releasing this if I ever finish it.)

Comment: I understand your overview. But can you add some more details on the exact problem you have hit. Q) Are you using OAuth2

Comment: I put everything I know up there, but I can see how it might be difficult to pick the exact problem out. Namely, the spreadsheet feed—despite working in the browser and the sharing permissions set (I think) so that no login is required—doesn't actually download when I try to get it in Python, just returning an empty binary string. And, no, I'm not using OAuth2. Would that help? It does seem to be a separate (non-default) module, though, and I'm trying to avoid as many of those as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Requres OAuth2 or a password.

If you log out of google and try again with your browser, it fails (It failed when I did logged out). It looks like it requires a google account.

I did have it working with and application password a while ago. But I now use OAuth2. Both are quite a bit of messing about compared to CSV.

Comment: All right, thanks! I do still wish there was a way of doing it without authentication, since I've set the spreadsheet up so you shouldn't need to log in, but that's apparently a problem with Google rather than Python's interface to it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case for a wrapper [library](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api) i once wrote. Let me know if you find it useful.